# Create a new Object based on a property and group by that property Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this

```
Data = [
{id: 1, name: "Dummy1", date:"2023-03-01"},
{id: 2, name: "Dummy2", date:"2023-03-04"},
{id: 3, name: "Dummy3", date:"2023-03-02"},
{id: 4, name: "Dummy4", date:"2023-03-01"}]
```

How do I get

```
[
{
2023-03-01: [{id:1, name: "Dummy1"},{id:4, name: "Dummy4"}]
},
{
2023-03-02: [{id:2, name: "Dummy2"}]
},
{
 2023-03-03: [{id:3, name: "Dummy3"}]
]
```

I have tried to map over Data and create a new object with the date property

```
data.map(item => { 
 let newbject = {}
 new object[item.date] = item
 })
```

But to be honest I don't really know how to achieve what it is I am wanting.

Comment: The callback function in `map` doesn't return a value. Can you describe with your own words what you expect `new object[item.date] = item` to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) with an object to store the values for each date.

```js
let data = [{id: 1, name: "Dummy1", date:"2023-03-01"},{id: 2, name: "Dummy2", date:"2023-03-04"},{id: 3, name: "Dummy3", date:"2023-03-02"},{id: 4, name: "Dummy4", date:"2023-03-01"}];
let res = Object.values(data.reduce((acc, {date, ...rest}) => {
  (acc[date] ??= {[date]: []})[date].push(rest);
  return acc;
}, {}));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Can you explain the double ?? please.

Comment: @Bwizard See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_assignment

Answer (score 1):

In this example, we use the reduce() method to iterate over each object in the data array. We initialize the accumulator (acc) as an empty object.

For each object, we check if the date already exists as a key in the accumulator object. If it doesn't exist, we create an empty array for that date key. We then push a new object with only the id and name properties into the array.

```
const data = [
  { id: 1, name: "Dummy1", date: "2023-03-01" },
  { id: 2, name: "Dummy2", date: "2023-03-04" },
  { id: 3, name: "Dummy3", date: "2023-03-02" },
  { id: 4, name: "Dummy4", date: "2023-03-01" }
];

const result = data.reduce((acc, item) => {
  const date = item.date;
  if (!acc[date]) {
    acc[date] = [];
  }
  acc[date].push({ id: item.id, name: item.name });
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```